# Hotmail in Firefox not saving login details

Tags: windows-7, firefox, automatic-logon

I have upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit.

I am using Firefox 3.6 Beta 5.  I have www.hotmail.com set as my homepage.

When I start Firefox it always asks for my login details. Even if I select to remember my password it never does so I always have to login to Hotmail when starting my browser.

Google Chrome works fine and always comes up with my email with no login issues after  logging in once and clicking the to remember my details check boxes.

Why is it not working in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not retain Hotmail credentials.

Here's a workaround:

**[Make Firefox Remember Passwords of Hotmail, Live, MSN & Yahoo Sites](http://dotnetwizard.net/soft-apps/make-firefox-remember-passwords-of-hotmail-live-msn-yahoo-sites/)**